# How does HETATM affects Phi-Psi angle of Protein?

Tags: biopython

I have a python script to measure the phi psi angles of protein of variable length and consists of multiple chains. But my script is not considering one amino acid residue before and after the HETATM. My input file is "1j73.pdb" which is having modified amino acid at 8th position (diaminobutyric acid) and my script is not considering 7th and 9th amino acid residue in phi-psi calculation.

My output file should contain phi-psi values for all the amino acid residues.
I am using the code given below to calculate dihedral angles.

http://www.warwick.ac.uk/go/peter_cock/python/ramachandran/calculate/
The code is written by Thomas Hamelryck's Bio.PDB module in Bio Python

Comment: Hello, do you mind linking the code to your question?

Comment: Hello!! I linked the code. Thank You!

Comment: have you tried editing HETATM to ATOM by hand for res 8 ??

Answer (score 0):

found out solution, despite dont understand how you got your code working without using `from Bio.PDB.Polypeptide import PPBuilder`:

```
import Bio.PDB
for model in Bio.PDB.PDBParser().get_structure("1J73", "1j73.pdb") :
    for chain in model :
        polypeptides = Bio.PDB.PPBuilder().build_peptides(chain, aa_only=False)
        for poly_index, poly in enumerate(polypeptides) :
            print( "Model %s Chain %s" % (str(model.id), str(chain.id))),
            print( "(part %i of %i)" % (poly_index+1, len(polypeptides))),
            print( "length %i" % (len(poly))),
            print( "from %s%i" % (poly[0].resname, poly[0].id[1])),
            print( "to %s%i" % (poly[-1].resname, poly[-1].id[1])),
            phi_psi = poly.get_phi_psi_list()
            for res_index, residue in enumerate(poly) :
                res_name = "%s%i" % (residue.resname, residue.id[1])
                print( res_name, phi_psi[res_index])
```

the solution is in:

`polypeptides = Bio.PDB.PPBuilder().build_peptides(chain, aa_only=False)`

instead of :

`polypeptides = Bio.PDB.PPBuilder().build_peptides(chain)`

see : https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/PDB/Polypeptide.py#L37

Comment: OK got it: https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/PDB/__init__.py